# Public or Private SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Good Morning,

I purchased an SSL certificate from Dynadot, Wildcard using a request from IIS. We are working with another company and they are asking for a public SSL because apparently no password is required? yet when I export from IIS it requires I set a password.

I am totally confused, and never really had anyone ask that of me before. can anyone help clarify?

Comment: This company will be hosting an API for us. I assumed that they would need our wildcard cert to host our domain on one of their servers. So I exported and set a password. Asked them for their PGP key so I can send the password for the exported cert, and they came back with, just send us a public cert, it doesn't need a password.

Comment: Okay, that makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are asking for the public key for the SSL certificate, that can be retrieved from IIS per this article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps

Alternatively, you can use the method you tried earlier to export the key but do not check the box to export the private key. By doing so, you should not be prompted to provide a password and thus will only export the public certificate (which includes the public key).

Comment: you know, it would have helped if I remembered to do it from the certificate manager snap in, in IIS that option is not there. Thank you.. !!

Comment: You're welcome. I had not remembered that the option to export from IIS without the private key was absent; I generally use the certificate manager. We both learn something today.